# get minimum value which is greater than some value from column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a pandas dataframe and would like to create a column `min_date_after_ref_date` which shows the minimum date after a given ref_date. I have the following code.

```
ref_date = datetime.strptime('2023-04-21 12:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,1,1,3], 'time_stamp': ['2023-04-19 12:05', '2023-04-21 12:45',
                                                 '2023-04-21 15:45', '2023-04-23 13:15', '2023-04-18 12:05']})
df = df.assign(time_stamp=pd.to_datetime(df.time_stamp))
df = df.assign(min_date_after_ref_date=df[df.time_stamp>ref_date].groupby('id').time_stamp.transform('min'))
```

and I get this

```
id  time_stamp  min_date_after_ref_date
0   1   2023-04-19 12:05:00 NaT
1   2   2023-04-21 12:45:00 2023-04-21 12:45:00
2   1   2023-04-21 15:45:00 2023-04-21 15:45:00
3   1   2023-04-23 13:15:00 2023-04-21 15:45:00
4   3   2023-04-18 12:05:00 NaT
```

but I would like there to be `2023-04-21 15:45:00` also in the first row (and not `NaN`), so that for each `id` there is always the same value of `min_date_after_ref_date`.
How can I change this?

Comment: there is no need for `groupby` if the reference is independent of any group

Comment: @mozway - So you think OP need `df.assign(min_date_after_ref_date=df.time_stamp.where(df.time_stamp>ref_date))` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) for set `NaT` if condition is `False`:

```
out = df.assign(min_date_after_ref_date=df.time_stamp.where(df.time_stamp>ref_date)
                                           .groupby(df['id'])
                                           .transform('min'))
print (out)
   id          time_stamp min_date_after_ref_date
0   1 2023-04-19 12:05:00     2023-04-21 15:45:00
1   2 2023-04-21 12:45:00     2023-04-21 12:45:00
2   1 2023-04-21 15:45:00     2023-04-21 15:45:00
3   1 2023-04-23 13:15:00     2023-04-21 15:45:00
4   3 2023-04-18 12:05:00                     NaT
```

Or use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) without `transform`:

```
out = df.assign(min_date_after_ref_date=df['id'].map(df[df.time_stamp>ref_date]
                                                     .groupby('id').time_stamp.min()))
print (df)
   id          time_stamp min_date_after_ref_date
0   1 2023-04-19 12:05:00     2023-04-21 15:45:00
1   2 2023-04-21 12:45:00     2023-04-21 12:45:00
2   1 2023-04-21 15:45:00     2023-04-21 15:45:00
3   1 2023-04-23 13:15:00     2023-04-21 15:45:00
4   3 2023-04-18 12:05:00                     NaT
```